# Using Validate function in Powerapps

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a Sharepoint online list with fields Sun, Mon and RatePerJob.  The RatePerJob is mandatory.  Either Sun or Mon must have a value.  All fields are numeric.
In the list settings I have this validation formula.

```
=AND(AND(RatePerJob>0,RatePerJob<50),OR(Sun>0,Mon>0))
```

I have a powerapp with a gallery and form linked to the Sharepoint list.
I want to avoid having to write lots of validation code in the powerapp.
How can I use the validate function in powerapps to submit the form if it's valid and to display an error message otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

Set the **OnSelect** property of the button as shown below:

```
If(Value(DataCardValue4.Text)>0 And Value(DataCardValue4.Text)<50 And (Value(DataCardValue2.Text)>0 Or Value(DataCardValue3.Text)>0),
    SubmitForm(Form1),
    Notify("ErrorTest", NotificationType.Error)
)
```

*Note,**DataCardValue4** is the datacard of RatePerJob column, **DataCardValue2** and **DataCardValue3** are the datacards in the Sun and Mon columns respectively.*

*You could also change the related datacard name more user friendly.*

Comment: Does this mean I have to do the validation in Powerapps and cannot use the validation that I have already set in the SharePoint list itself.  I was hoping the Validate function in powerapps would stop me having to write the code above.

Comment: Simillarly there may be a way to simply check if the form is valid using the validation rules that I've already put into the SharePoint list.